# Loading a model inside a module from API in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have one module Foo in my codeigniter HMVC. Also I have an api controller inside my application/controllers. I want to load a model inside application/module/foo/models from application/controllers/testapi

I have tested it by autoload  as

```
$autoload['model'] = array('foo/Foo_model');
```

and called from testapi

```
$this->load->model('Foo_model');
```

But its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$this->load->model('foo/foo_model');
```

from your controller.

then call model's function like this

```
$this->foo_model->function_name();
```

save model in `application/modules/foo/models/Foo_model.php`

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter loads all possible models from `application/models`, I would suggest you modify the path of your models to something like `application/models/modules` with this you can load your model using

`$this->load->model('modules/foo/Foo_model')`

If you do want to retain your folder structure, I suggest you look at the constant paths of CodeIgniter and start modifying them to your will (although this is not really recommended).